# Airwatch API Internal Application Install : Begin Internal Application Install

Tags: post, request, mdm, airwatch

Currently trying to integrate Airwatch deployment to our build process. After uploading out IPA to airwatch through Upload Blob the Being Internal Application POST request requires both a TransactionId obtained from uploading an application as chucks and a BlobId obtained from Upload Blob. If I omit the TransactionId from my request the request returns an Internal Server Error, but if left in, returns a 4XX error saying the transaction id does not exist or is invalid.

Request:

```
{
"BlobId":"<omitted>",
"DeviceType":"2",
"TransactionId":"a",
"ApplicationName":"Airwatch Test",
"SupportedModels":
{
    "Model":
    [{
        "ModelId":1
    }]
},
"PushMode":"Auto",
}
```

Comment: I'm having a similar issue. Upload blob succeeds but I cannot save that blobId. When I use a different client to upload the blob as binary I can save and assign without problems.

Comment: @fluzzam how were you able to use upload blob API?

Answer (score 1):

If you have sent your binaries via the UploadBLOB call, you will need to specify the BlobId but should leave the TransactionID out of the JSON. You are probably receiving the "400" because you are missing the 
"ModelName" tag from the Model object and the comma after the PushMode statement should be removed to make your JSON valid. If your authorization header and tenant key header is setup correctly, the following JSON payload should work with the "BeginInstall" call.

```
{
"BlobId":"<add you blobid here>",
"DeviceType":"2",
"ApplicationName":"Airwatch Test",
"SupportedModels":
{
   "Model":
   [{
     "ModelId":1,
     "ModelName":"iPhone"
   }]
},
"PushMode":"Auto"
}
```

Comment: can you please share the code for upload blob ? i am bit confused about  the uploading